# Can SOAP services support Rest Services && REST services can support SOAP services

Tags: java, rest, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working on web-services, i need some clarification on SOAP Web-services and REST Web-services.

1.Is it possible to say all SOAP services , can be  support to  REST services.

2.Is it possible to say all REST services ,  can be  support to SOAP services.

Comment: They are different paradigms, but what do you mean 'can use all' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOAP Service and RestSerivce have different "service definition" ( request structure - response structure - endpoint  - format)

If you mean  "soap service can be called as reset service" then NO. you have to expose two services one for rest and the other for soap.

If you mean  "soap service can call rest service" then Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Web services provides an interface. In `SOAP` you have `wsdl` exposed and `REST` provides you a `URI` with method type. Once your interface is reached, internally you can call or process anything. Hence, it's possible to use `REST` from `SOAP` and vice-versa.